# Showing unnumbered sections in header using two different layouts in fancyhdr

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, fancyhdr

I use two header layouts - first of introductions and second for dictionary. I want ot set the unnumbered sections headings into header in the first header together with page number. Minimal example follows:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[icelandic, czech, english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x, utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{tipa}
\newcommand{\entry}[2]{\hangpara{2em}{1}\textsf{\textbf{#1}}\ #2\markboth{#1}{#1}\par}\nopagebreak[4]
\newcommand*{\dictchar}[1]{\centerline{\LARGE\textbf{#1}}\par}
\fancypagestyle{basicstyle}{%
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}
\fancypagestyle{dictstyle}{%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\textsf{\textbf{\rightmark\ -- \leftmark}}}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\textsf{\textbf{\thepage}}}}
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{basicstyle}
\chapter*{1. Průvodce po slovníku}
\clearpage
\section*{1. Heslové slovo}
\subsection*{1.1 Řazení slov }
\blindtext

\pagestyle{dictstyle}
\chapter*{3. Islandsko-český studijní slovník}
\clearpage
\entry{{a.n.}}{{\small{ zkr}}{\textsl{\textbf{að eðan}}}\foreignlanguage{czech}{{ pod, dole}}}
\entry{{afl··vak|i}}{{\textipa{[{a}{\textsubring{b}}{\textsubring{l}}{v}{a}{\r{\textObardotlessj}}{\textsci}]}}{\small{ m}}{\small{ (-a, -ar)}}\foreignlanguage{czech}{{ hnací síla, motiv}}}
\entry{{af··|segja}}{{\textipa{[{a}{f}{s}{ei}{j}{a}]}}{\small{ v}}{\small{ (-sagði, -sagt)}}{\small{ acc}}{\textit{ (neita)}}\foreignlanguage{czech}{{ odmítnout}}}
\end{document}
```

How can I change the basicstyle so that it shows unnumbered sections with page numbers?

Comment: Example is now compilable, sorry for delay. Can you show me how can I achieve that unnumbered section appears there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This manual numbering looks a bit odd:

```
\chapter*{1. Průvodce po slovníku}
\section*{1. Heslové slovo}
\subsection*{1.1 Řazení slov}
```

You typeset a book, a dictionary, which could contain many sections and subsections. If you insert or remove a section or subsection, you would have to modify all following numbers manually. Also, it could easily lead to numbering mistakes. LaTeX could do it for you automatically. Just use the unstarred commands, let LaTeX do the numbering.

```
\chapter{Průvodce po slovníku}
\section{Heslové slovo}
\subsection{Řazení slov}
```

This also solves the problem of header markers: `\chapter` and `\section` produce entries for the header automatically, by `\markboth` or `\markright`, respectively, the starred versions don't. However, if you insist on starred versions, you could call `\markboth` or `\markright` yourself.

Furthermore, if `basicstyle` pages should show sections and page numbers, use such `\fancyhead` commands within `\fancypagestyle{basicstyle}{...}`, with `\rightmark` and `\leftmark` which contain the title values.

As discussed in the comments,here's a full example with your own heading marks.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{basicstyle}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\textsf{\textbf{\chaptitle\ -- \sectitle}}}
  \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\textsf{\textbf{\thepage}}}}
\pagestyle{basicstyle}
\newcommand*{\sectitle}{}
\renewcommand*{\sectionmark}[1]{%
    \renewcommand*{\sectitle}{#1}}
\newcommand*{\chaptitle}{}
\renewcommand*{\chaptermark}[1]{%
    \renewcommand*{\chaptitle}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Průvodce po slovníku}
\clearpage
\section{Heslové slovo}
\subsection{Řazení slov }
text
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have tried to use `\chapter` and `\section` numbered but there is problem. The heading appears only on first page and later there appears headwords instead of chapter - because I use also examples of `\entry` in the first section.

Comment: You could set an use your own macros then, in `\fancypagestyle{basicstyle}{...}`. Such as `\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\textsf{\textbf{\chaptitle -- \sectitle}}}` and set those title macros by `\renewcommand` when needed, i.e. after `\chapter` or `\section`.

Comment: Can you set an example of `\renewcommand` for `\section` and should I place that `renewcommand` after each `\section`?

Comment: You could redefine `\sectionmark`, however it could also be done manually after each `\section` if desired. I added an example.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. And I will study the example to understand how to use `\renewcommand`.